# Copy content of TinyMCE using data-id

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, tinymce

I have a Wordpress UserFrontend Pro implementation of TinyMCE where the html is:

```
<body id="tinymce" class="mce-content-body post_content_442 post-type-page post-status-publish page-template-default locale-en-us mceContentBody webkit wp-editor html5-captions" data-id="post_content_442" contenteditable="true"><p>The text that I want to copy</p></body>
```

I am trying to copy the content inside ie:

```
<p>The text that I want to copy</p>
```

in this case.

I tried using

```
$('[data-id="post_content_442"]')
```

but this prints out the entire HTML itself.

How do I print only the entered text with html formatting? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the input is inside an iframe with ID post_content_442_ifr. So

```
$jq2("#post_content_442_ifr").contents().find("#tinymce").html();
```

allows me to select the required texts.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

$('[data-id="post_content_442"] p').text();

Comment: Unfortunately, this only gives a blank text